# Help understanding some OpenGL stuff

Tags: c++, opengl, actor

I am working with some code to create a triangle that moves with arrow keys. I want to create a second object that moves independently. This is where I am having trouble, I have created the second actor, but cannot get it to move. There is too much code to post it all so I will just post a little and see if anyone can help at all.

ogl_test.cpp

```
#include "platform.h"
#include "srt/scheduler.h"

#include "model.h"
#include "controller.h"

#include "model_module.h"
#include "graphics_module.h"

class blob : public actor {
public:
    blob(float x, float y) : actor(math::vector2f(x, y)) { }

    void render() {
        transform();

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glVertex3f(0.25f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
            glVertex3f(-.5f, 0.25f, -5.0f);
            glVertex3f(-.5f, -0.25f, -5.0f);
        glEnd();
        end_transform();
    }
    void update(controller& c, float dt) {
        if (c.left_key) {
            rho += pi / 9.0f * dt;
            c.left_key = false;
        }
        if (c.right_key) {
            rho -= pi / 9.0f * dt;
            c.right_key = false;
        }
        if (c.up_key) {
            v += .1f * dt;
            c.up_key = false;
        }
        if (c.down_key) {
            v -= .1f * dt;
            if (v < 0.0) { v = 0.0; }
            c.down_key = false;
        }
        actor::update(c, dt);
    }
};

class enemyOne : public actor {
public:
    enemyOne(float x, float y) : actor(math::vector2f(x, y)) { }

    void render() {
        transform();

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glVertex3f(0.25f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
            glVertex3f(-.5f, 0.25f, -5.0f);
            glVertex3f(-.5f, -0.25f, -5.0f);
        glEnd();
        end_transform();
    }
    void update(controller& c, float dt) {
        if (c.left_key) {
            rho += pi / 9.0f * dt;
            c.left_key = false;
        }
        if (c.right_key) {
            rho -= pi / 9.0f * dt;
            c.right_key = false;
        }
        if (c.up_key) {
            v += .1f * dt;
            c.up_key = false;
        }
        if (c.down_key) {
            v -= .1f * dt;
            if (v < 0.0) { v = 0.0; }
            c.down_key = false;
        }
        actor::update(c, dt);
    }
};

int APIENTRY WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    char* lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow
)
{

    model m;
    controller control(m);

    srt::scheduler scheduler(33);
    srt::frame* model_frame = new srt::frame(scheduler.timer(), 0, 1, 2);
    srt::frame* render_frame = new srt::frame(scheduler.timer(), 1, 1, 2);
    model_frame->add(new model_module(m, control));

    render_frame->add(new graphics_module(m));

    scheduler.add(model_frame);
    scheduler.add(render_frame);

    blob* prime = new blob(0.0f, 0.0f);
    m.add(prime);
    m.set_prime(prime);

    enemyOne* primeTwo = new enemyOne(2.0f, 0.0f);
    m.add(primeTwo);
    m.set_prime(primeTwo);

    scheduler.start();
    control.start();

    return 0;
}
```

model.h

```
#include <vector>
#include "vec.h"

const double pi = 3.14159265358979323;

class controller;

using math::vector2f;

class actor {
public:
    vector2f P;
    float theta;
    float v;
    float rho;

    actor(const vector2f& init_location) :
        P(init_location),
        rho(0.0),
        v(0.0),
        theta(0.0)
    { }
    virtual void render() = 0;
    virtual void update(controller&, float dt) {
        float v1 = v;
        float theta1 = theta + rho * dt;
        vector2f P1 = P + v1 * vector2f(cos(theta1), sin(theta1));
        if (P1.x < -4.5f || P1.x > 4.5f) { P1.x = -P1.x; }
        if (P1.y < -4.5f || P1.y > 4.5f) { P1.y = -P1.y; }
        v = v1;
        theta = theta1;
        P = P1;
    }

protected:
    void transform() {
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(P.x, P.y, 0.0f);
        glRotatef(theta * 180.0f / pi, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //Rotate about the z-axis
    }
    void end_transform() {
        glPopMatrix();
    }
};

class model {
private:
    typedef std::vector<actor*> actor_vector;
    actor_vector actors;
public:
    actor* _prime;

    model() { }

    void add(actor* a) {
        actors.push_back(a);
    }
    void set_prime(actor* a) {
        _prime = a;
    }
    void update(controller& control, float dt) {
        for (actor_vector::iterator i = actors.begin(); i != actors.end(); ++i) {
            (*i)->update(control, dt);
        }
    }
    void render() {
        for (actor_vector::iterator i = actors.begin(); i != actors.end(); ++i) {
            (*i)->render();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I know that the code I have below the enemyOne actor is not correct, but when I change it, it no longer compiles so I left it like that

Comment: Is this enough for people to see what I am working with?

Comment: Actually, I think you presented too much code (and not completed, working examples) so we have trouble decoding what you did.

Comment: I was not sure exactly what to show you guys.

Comment: @shinjuo: Try to present an example code as short and as relevant as possible. This usually involve opening a new file, make a `int main()` function, and start coding some quick and dirty tests.

Comment: @shinjuo: You got very unlucky when you first asked this question, all the relevant code is here.  I guess you're in a timezone quite different from most of the experts and your question fell off the front page before any of them woke up and saw it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `blob` is erasing the keypresses before the second actor sees them:

```
if (c.left_key) {
   rho += pi / 9.0f * dt;
   c.left_key = false; // <-- HERE
}
```

Clearing the keyboard state after each frame should not be the concern of any single actor, the controller itself should do that.

Answer (score 1):

Both blob and enemyOne both have an update function that checks the arrow keys to see whether to move. If you commented out all of the if statements inside one of the update function then it should not move anymore. Alternatively, you could change the if statements in the update function to check other keys and use those to control the other object.

EDIT: As noted in another answer, when you set c.left_key = false; (or one on the other keys) you prevent any of the other actors from seeing that the key was pressed. Either not passing the controller around as a reference, or removing these lines of code should fix this.